# Do not add string on last iteration of loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split

I have an array, one of the values is a string.  I need to split that string, append the name of the attribute (j + ' | ') and insert an OR between the two values.

As it stands, it adds and OR after BOTH values, however I do not want it appended to the last value.  The number of values can be dynamic, in this case there are two values after I split it, but in some cases there may be as many as 10, 14, etc...  How can I keep my loop from adding an OR to the last value?

//simplified code here:

```
        obj1.SegmentsSummary[h][j] = "Hi |OR| Bye";
        var varname = obj1.SegmentsSummary[h][j].split(" |OR| ");
        obj1.SegmentsSummary[h][j] = '';
        for (k = 0; k < varname.length; k++) {
        obj1.SegmentsSummary[h][j] +=  j + ' | ' + varname[k] + '  |OR|  ';
```

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Either check in the loop `if k === varname.length -1` or append the OR to the beginning of the string and start with the first element instead of an empty string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you do is you set a sentinel value (ex. var sentinalValue = varname.length -1) then you add a condition looking for that value (ex. if(sentinalValue = k)). That way you know you're on the LAST iteration of the for loop. Then, handle objt1 differently for that one iteration (inside the for loop!).

Comment: No problem...I appreciate that.